# Job server - remove Gearman worker function from queue

Tags: php, gearman, job-scheduling, supervisord, process-control

We're using Gearman along with Supervisord to queue and run jobs on our server.  One issue I cannot seem to be able to solve is completley removing Gearman workers from the job queue.  I've tried removing both client/worker source files as well as calling [`GearmanWorker::unregister`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanworker.unregister.php) from a different worker.  When running `$ gearadmin --status` I still see the worker function within the job queue.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

You need *gearadmin --drop-function XXX*